# UnsatisfiedLinkError when running TypeDB on an M1 MacBook

Tags: java, unsatisfiedlinkerror, vaticle-typedb

I tried running TypeDB on my M1 MacBook using `./typedb server`, but it results in the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /var/folders/5v/95_mbj013y93vsmc8xps0stm0000gp/T/librocksdbjni8182124459810412816.jnilib
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2393)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:755)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:1953)
```

This error looks like it might occur when running a Java program with an incompatible JDK. What can I do to resolve it?

(*Disclaimer - TypeDB maintainer here.*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of the TypeDB 2.19.0 release, the `mac` and `linux` distributions support both `x86_64`/`amd64` and `arm64`/`aarch64` architectures natively.

These versions are faster than using emulation to run the x86_64 distributions on Macs in particular.

Installation is now as simple as installing a Java runtime that is applicable to your native OS+architecture, and then installing TypeDB for your OS via the apt/brew distribution channels or from the Github releases page: https://github.com/vaticle/typedb/releases

Answer (score 7):

## TypeDB v2.19 or above

As of TypeDB 2.19.0, TypeDB supports native Mac and Linux `arm` architectures. Simply install a native Java runtime to run TypeDB.

## Old versions of TypeDB

> ⚠️ Prior to TypeDB 2.19.0, there were no distributions available for `aarch64` (ARM). As of Jul 6, 2023, the [best solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76627424/2902555) is to [upgrade](https://github.com/vaticle/typedb/releases) to TypeDB 2.19.0 or above. If doing so through Homebrew, ensure you are using an ARM64 installation of `brew` (i.e. the default).

If the running JDK targets `aarch64` (ARM), the architecture used by an M1 Mac, then an `UnsatisfiedLinkError` is thrown at startup. There is no native ARM build of TypeDB <v2.19, so in order for older versions of TypeDB to run correctly on an M1 MacBook you need to ensure that a JDK that targets `x64` architecture is installed.

For example, to install Eclipse Temurin (based upon OpenJDK):

1. Visit https://adoptium.net/en-GB/temurin/releases/?version=11 to browse Temurin releases
2. Select the `.pkg` distribution of `JDK 11` with operating system `MacOS` and architecture `x64`
3. Download and install the Java binary displayed in the list below
4. Verify that Java was installed correctly by running `java --version`; the output should match the downloaded JDK version

*Please note that this method relies on MacOS's [Rosetta translation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple-silicon/about-the-rosetta-translation-environment), which will inflict a performance overhead.*

Comment: adoptopenjdk.net now recommend we download from adoption.net, so perhaps we should update the answer to it? Also worth suggesting users to download the PKG distribution for ease of installation.

Comment: Updated with the new information.

Answer (score 4):

My computer is MacBookAir M1. And I encountered this problem too.

I tried Java 17 and Java 8, and both were filed. Finally, when I **switch to Java 11, the error disappeared.** Hope this helps.